# CQ5-How to add rte plugin in custom widget

Tags: aem, richtext

I have added richtext in the custom widget but i dont know how to add aditinal plugins for richtext.

Please help how we can achieve the same.
I am trying to add superscript/subscript in the richtext but not able to achieve the same.

Comment: What custom widget are you talking about ? Please add more information on widget, if possible the custom widget code and the rte code used inside the custom widget.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a code snippet that I've used to add this functionality to a richtext field.

```
 <text
        jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
        hideLabel="{Boolean}true"
        name="./text"
        xtype="richtext">
    <rtePlugins jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
        <subsuperscript
                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                features="*"/>
    </rtePlugins>
</text>
```

This snippet belongs in the **dialog.xml** of your custom component.

please have a look at [the documentation for configuring the rich text editor](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/administering/configuring_rich_text_editor.html) for more information.

Comment: I know this is an old answer, but today this was really helpful to me as the documentation doesn't show an example as clear as yours. Thanks!